# read.bmp() mismatch between predicted and actual number of bytes in the file

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a BMP file in R using the `read.bmp` function in the `bmp` package. However, I get the following error:

> Error in read.bmp("tiger.bmp") :mismatch between predicted and actual number of bytes in image

I am not sure how can I get past this error. Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you somehow share the bmp file you are using?

Answer (score 3):

That message means that read.bmp is expecting a certain byte depth, 4 bytes per integer in the binary, with each integer composing a part of the pixel, which you can see in this section of code. The script is defining and testing the dimensions of the file based on the color bit depth and header definitions.

If you look at this code which is under the hood of the function:

```
  bytes_pixel=h$depth / 8
  row_width_bytes=h$width * bytes_pixel
  # bmp rows are written to lenth of nearest 4 bytes
  rounded_row_width_bytes = ceiling(row_width_bytes/4)*4
  bytes_to_trim = row_width_bytes %% 4
  bytes_to_read=rounded_row_width_bytes * h$height
  if(h$bmp_bytesz==0) {
    if(Verbose) warning("invalid byte size information for image")
  }
  else if(h$bmp_bytesz != bytes_to_read)
    stop("mismatch between predicted and actual number of bytes in image")
```

`h$bmp_bytesz=4`

The `h$`  fields are all defined header settings which set the byte depth of 1L to 4 for various dimensions of the image. This section is checking to see that the file is coming in as expected. It is either 8, 24 or 32 bit because it made it past the first warning above this section. It stopped because there is a problem with the encoded dimensions of the file.

If the file is correctly formatted and not damaged, with 3x8 channels, it should come in properly. (or black and white with 1x8 channels)

Try running:

`is.bmp('tiger.bmp')` to see if it returns that it is a viable Windows BMP file.

Comment: I opened the bounty because I have a bmp that cannot be read in R and can be read in Python. The is.bmp function returns FALSE as you indicated. I uploaded the file here: https://github.com/jon-nagra/Stack-Sample-Files/blob/master/replay.bmp 
What can be the reason for the error with that file? In any case, thank you for the explanation about the inners of read.bmp, I will debug that part of the code to see what is going on.

Comment: I just played with it a bit and had two errors opening it. Looking around in photoshop it seems fine. It did show up as rgb & 8 bit which is odd. But changing to grayscale did not fix the issue...ried two other methods also not working. I was able to save it as a tiff file (which is also not compressed and read it instantly. If that does not destroy your process, you can try that using `tiff` package readTIFF. If not I can dropbox you the image if you like

Comment: and...when I tried is.bmp it said TRUE...but would not open it. You might be able to fix it with a file repair download for images. But resaving as TIFF was pretty easy.

Comment: You are right `is.bmp` returns TRUE. I was able to change the format to 256 colours using paint. However, I will have several images like that one (they are provided by a laser camera) and I will need an automatic approach. I will likely switch to python for this analysis, but it is strange that the function fails to read a bmp.

Comment: I used three different r functions and they all struggled. The file is a 3.0 generation bitmap. Perhaps if you can get the laser to save to 5.0 the issue might be resolved. There is something wrong with the header text. Also, if it will save a TIFF those are breezy to work with in R!

Comment: I was able to read the bmp with `imager` package's `load.image` function. The documentation says it uses `readbitmap` for reading bmp-s but it probably has switched to other package in this case.

Comment: I could not get that package to load on my mac...I am glad it worked for you! Good luck with your project!